# Screen Display Settings for Migraine Sufferer

Tags: mac, display, brightness

I hope I'm posting this in the correct place but if not, a recommendation would be great as I've been searching for a while.

Ok, so here's my issue. I use my computer for many hours per day. I don't want to stop writing code and I like working at night. However, I've always been a migraine sufferer (all my life) and I find that I'm regularly suffering from migraines that can last for a few days after heavy screen use.

Does anyone else have this issue and if so, have you ever found a display setting or screen type that actually works for reducing migraine events?

Many thanks to all who take the time to read this. p.s. I use Macbook Pro

Comment: [Tips For Heavy Computer Users – Migraines / Eye Strain and other related Issues](https://www.whitworth.edu/cms/media/whitworth/documents/administration/educational-support-services/tips-for-heavy-computer-users.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

All Macbook Pro have a screen with [Pulse Width Modulation](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Why-Pulse-Width-Modulation-PWM-is-such-a-headache.270240.0.html) PWM, which can be terrible for your eyes and for your brain: It's switching on and off 65'000 times per second (The frequency depends on the model).

**PWM gets worse with a lower screen brightness**, as the basic brightness of the pulses remain the same, while they become shorter: so your eyes get a very strong "Flash" which is in no proportion to the "perceived brightness". So it is particularly bad for working at night

You can mitigate this partially by using [Lunar](https://lunar.fyi/) and limiting the lowest brightness of the backlight (to something like 40%), then using subzero dimming to reduce the overall brightness, as [explained in detail in this thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-14-m2pro-pwm-solution.2386836/post-32101983).

However, **the best would be to use an external monitor without PWM**. The spec to look for is **DC-Dimming**, which lowers the voltage of the backlight to reduce the brightness. Moreover, most good review websites check the monitors for PWM. An external monitor will also be bigger than the built-in screen, allowing you to increase the display font, which will help relax your eyes even further.

I got aware of this whole issue because I changed from PC to MAC, but after two months I was literally losing my Eyesight, with violent headaches. I had to sell off my Macbook Pro and get a PC.

I now have a 100% Eyesafe screen with DC-Dimming & Bluelight filter, and no pixel flicker. I would not give it away for anything in the world.

Comment: Wow. That's extremely informative. I had absolutely no idea about this. I only purchased the Mac about a year ago and so it certainly would explain the increase in migraine episodes. I'll try the suggestions and also start looking for monitor. 
All the best.

Comment: @Sisao To let you know how this Community works: If this answer is useful for you, please upvote. Should it resolve your issue, please mark it as Correct Answer. Thank you.